# partial differential equation $y^2\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x\partial y} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Helle everybody, i have a problem with a partial differential equation, I tried to work but it's not true
$$\begin{array}{l}
 y^2\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x \, \partial y} + \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} - \frac{2}{y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 \\[6pt]
 u(x,1) = 1 - x \\[6pt]
 \left. \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right|_{y = 1} = 3
 \end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $v=u_y$.  The equation is then 1st order in $v$:

$$y^2 v_x + v_y - \frac{2}{y} v = 0$$

$$v(x,1) = 3$$

This may be solved using the method of characteristics to determine $v(x,y)$; then use $v = u_y$, $u(x,1)=1-x$ to find $u(x,y)$.

I leave the details to the reader; I get

$$u(x,y) = 5 y - 2 y \log y - x - 4$$

**ADDENDUM**

The method of characteristic solution for $v$ is as follows. Parametrize $x$, $y$, and $v$ in terms of parameters $s$ and $t$ as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = y^2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 1$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = -\frac{2}{y}$$

subject to the initial conditions

$$x(s,0)=s$$

$$y(s,0)=1$$

$$v(s,0)=3$$

Solving this system, I get

$$y(s,t) = t+1$$

$$v(s,t) = 3 - 2 \log(t+1) \implies v(x,y) = 3 - 2 \log y$$

Integrate over $y$  to get $u(x,y)$:

$$u(x,y) = 3 y - 2 (y \log y -y) + f(x)$$

Use the condition $u(x,1)=1-x$ to get the final result.

Comment: Could you give more details? I have tried but..,

Comment: Are you at all familiar with the method of characteristics?  I can write up my solution to some degree, but I am not prepared to give an entire exposition on the subject.  I probably should have asked you what you have tried, and in what context you have encountered the problem.

Comment: I wrote my solution on this page. So you can check where is my mistake?

Comment: I found a solution that is:  $u(x,y) = {y^3} - x$

Answer (score 0):

I have done this as; howerver i am embarrass when use the condition:
$$\begin{array}{l}
 a = 1;b = y^2/2;c = 0 =  > b^2 - ac = \frac{y^2}{4} =  > \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - ac }}{a} = \frac{y^2/2 \pm y^2/2}{1} = \left[ \begin{array}{l}
 0 \\ 
 {y^2} \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{dx}}{{dy}} = 0 =  > dx = 0 =  > x = C =  >  \\ 
 \frac{{dx}}{{dy}} = {y^2} =  > dx = {y^2}dy =  > C = x - \frac{{{y^3}}}{3} =  > {\rm{  }} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.{\rm{ =  > }} \\ 
 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial \xi ^2}{\left( {\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial y}}} \right)^2} + \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {\eta ^2}}}{\left( {\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial y}}} \right)^2} + 2\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial \xi \partial \eta }}\left( {\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial y}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial y}}} \right) + \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \xi }}\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}\xi }}{{\partial {y^2}}}} \right) + \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }}\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}\eta }}{{\partial {y^2}}}} \right) \\ 
  =  > (1) \\ 
 \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial x\partial y}} = \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {\xi ^2}}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial y}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {\eta ^2}}}\left( {\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial y}}} \right) + \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial \xi \partial \eta }}\left( {\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial x}}\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial y}}\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial x}}} \right) + \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \xi }}\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}\xi }}{{\partial x\partial y}}} \right) + \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }}\left( {\frac{{{\partial ^2}\eta }}{{\partial x\partial y}}} \right) \\ 
  =  > (2) \\ 
 \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial y}} = \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \xi }}.\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{\partial y}} + \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }}\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial y}} =  > (3) \\ 
 (1)(2)(3) =  > (*): - {y^4}\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {\eta ^2}}} - {y^4}\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial \xi \partial \eta }} + {y^4}\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial {\eta ^2}}} + 0 + 0 - 2y\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }} - \frac{2}{y}\left[ {{y^2}\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }}} \right] = 0 \\ 
  =  >  - {y^4}\frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial \xi \partial \eta }} - 4y\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }} = 0 =  > {\rm{    }}(**) \\ 
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \eta  = x - \frac{{{y^3}}}{3} \\ 
 \xi  = x \\ 
 \end{array} \right. =  > \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 {y^3} = 3(\xi  - \eta ) \\ 
 x = \xi  \\ 
 \end{array} \right. =  > (**) =  >
 \end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}
 Let:\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }} = V(\xi ,\eta ) =  > \frac{{{\partial ^2}u}}{{\partial \xi \partial \eta }} = \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial \xi }} =  > 3(\xi  - \eta )\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial \xi }} + 4V = 0 =  >  \\ 
 \frac{{\partial V}}{V} =  - \frac{4}{3}\frac{{\partial \xi }}{{(\xi  - \eta )}} =  > \ln V =  - \frac{4}{3}\ln(\xi  - \eta ) - \underbrace {\ln F(\eta )}_{C{\rm{ons t    C}}} =  >  {V(\xi ,\eta ) = F(\eta ){{(\xi  - \eta )}^{ - 4/3}}}\\ 
 From:\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }} = V(\xi ,\eta ) =  > \frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial \eta }} = F(\eta ){(\xi  - \eta )^{ - 4/3}} =  > \partial u = F(\eta ){(\xi  - \eta )^{ - 4/3}}\partial \eta  \\ 
  =  > {u(\xi ,\eta ) = \underbrace {\int {F(\eta ){{(\xi  - \eta )}^{ - 4/3}}\partial \eta } }_{G(\eta )} + \underbrace {\Phi (\xi )}_{C{\rm{ons}}t{\rm{ C}}}} =>{u(\xi ,\eta ) = G(\eta ) + \Phi (\xi )}
{\rm{   =  > }} \\ 
 {\rm{ =  >   }}u(x,y) = G(x - \frac{{{y^3}}}{3}) + \Phi (x){\rm{     (***)}} \\ 
 {\rm{ Now we apply condition of u into (***)}} \\ 
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 u(x,1) = 1 - x =  > G(x - \frac{1}{3}) + \Phi (x){\rm{  }} \\ 
 {\left. {\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial y}}} \right|_{y = 1}} = 3 =  >  - {y^2}G'(x - \frac{{{y^3}}}{3}){|_{y = 1}} + 0 = 3 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. =  > \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 G\left( {x - \frac{1}{3}} \right) + \Phi (x){\rm{   = 1 - x}} \\ 
  - G'\left( {x - \frac{1}{3}} \right) = 3 \\ 
 \end{array} \right. =  > \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 G\left( {x - \frac{1}{3}} \right) + \Phi (x){\rm{   = 1 - x}} \\ 
 G\left( {x - \frac{1}{3}} \right) =  - 3y + C \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
  \\ 
 \end{array}$$
$${ =  > \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \Phi (x) = 1 - x + 3y - C \\ 
 G\left( {x - \frac{1}{3}} \right) =  - 3y + C \\ 
 \end{array} \right. =  > \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \Phi (x) = 1 - x + 3y - C \\ 
 G\left( {x - \frac{{{y^3}}}{3}} \right) = ?????????????????????? \\ 
 \end{array} \right.}$$